# Custom post page handler methods not hitting. It all goes to OnGet. (ASP.NET Razor Pages)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

Every time I submit my post form, it does not hit any of my custom post page handler methods. Refer to my code below:

## PageModel

```
namespace Abby.Web.Pages.Admin.Order {
    public class ManageOrderModel : PageModel {

        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public List<OrderDetailsVM> orderDetailsVMs { get; set; }

        public ManageOrderModel(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        public void OnGet() {
            orderDetailsVMs = new List<OrderDetailsVM>();

            List<OrderHeader> orderHeaders = _unitOfWork
                                            .OrderHeader
                                            .GetAll(u => u.OrderStatus == StaticDetails.StatusSubmitted ||
                                                u.OrderStatus == StaticDetails.StatusInProcess).ToList();
            foreach (OrderHeader orderHeader in orderHeaders) {
                OrderDetailsVM indiv = new() {
                    OrderHeader = orderHeader,
                    OrderDetails = _unitOfWork.OrderDetails.GetAll(u => u.OrderHeaderId == orderHeader.Id).ToList()
                };
                orderDetailsVMs.Add(indiv);
            }
        }

        public IActionResult OnPostOrderInProcess(int orderId) {
            _unitOfWork.OrderHeader.UpdateStatus(orderId, StaticDetails.StatusInProcess);
            _unitOfWork.Save();

            return RedirectToPage("ManageOrder");
        }

        public IActionResult OnPostOrderReady(int orderId) {
            _unitOfWork.OrderHeader.UpdateStatus(orderId, StaticDetails.StatusReady);
            _unitOfWork.Save();

            return RedirectToPage("ManageOrder");
        }

        public IActionResult OnPostOrderCancel(int orderId) {
            _unitOfWork.OrderHeader.UpdateStatus(orderId, StaticDetails.StatusCancelled);
            _unitOfWork.Save();

            return RedirectToPage("ManageOrder");
        }
    }
}
```

## View

```
@page
@model Abby.Web.Pages.Admin.Order.ManageOrderModel
@using Abby.Utility
@{
} 

<h1 class="text-primary py-3">Manage Orders</h1>
<form method="post" asp-page="ManageOrder">
    <div class="container row bg-white p-2 mb-3 rounded">
        @foreach (var item in Model.orderDetailsVMs) {
            <div class="col-12 pb-3 pt-3 mt-4 border  rounded">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        Order Number : @item.OrderHeader.Id
                        <ul class="text-info">
                            @foreach (var details in item.OrderDetails) {
                                <li>@details.Name x @details.Count</li>
                            }

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 pb-2">
                        <div class="input-group pb-2">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text bg-secondary border rounded-0">Time</span>
                            </div>
                            <input value="@item.OrderHeader.PickupTime" type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" readonly />
                        </div>
                        <textarea asp-for="@item.OrderHeader.Comments" readonly class="rounded border form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3 offset-1 d-flex align-content-center">
                        <div class="col-12">

                            @if (item.OrderHeader.OrderStatus == StaticDetails.StatusSubmitted) {
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control mb-3 rounded-0"
                                    asp-page-handler="OrderInProcess" asp-route-orderId ="@item.OrderHeader.Id" formmethod="post">
                                    <i class="bi bi-check-square"></i> &nbsp; Start Cooking
                                </button>
                            }
                            @if (item.OrderHeader.OrderStatus == StaticDetails.StatusInProcess) {
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control mb-3 rounded-0"
                                    asp-page-handler="OrderReady" asp-route-orderId="@item.OrderHeader.Id">
                                    <i class="bi bi-emoji-laughing"></i> &nbsp; Order Ready
                                </button>
                            }
                            
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning form-control mb-3 rounded-0"
                                asp-page="ManageOrder" asp-page-handler="OrderCancel" asp-route-orderId="@item.OrderHeader.Id">
                                <i class="bi bi-x-square-fill"></i> &nbsp; Cancel Order
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</form>
```

Been debugging this for a while and can't still find where the problem is.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

My post handlers not hitting. Form always hits the OnGet method.

Comment: Hi @garthzx, could you pls press F12 in the browser when you run the app and search the element for the buttons and check how is the button generated html like? Pls share the screenshot or html code which is generated in the browser.

Comment: Hi @Rena, gladly. Here is the screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/5NmoKMB

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

In Program.cs, I simply removed this line of code I added before:

```
var options = new RewriteOptions()
.AddRedirect("(.*)/$", "$1", 301 /* Moved Permanently */);
app.UseRewriter(options);
```

This is just code to remove trailing slashes in the address bar. For instance, if the URL were to be "/product/aymqwu981/", it will be translated to "/product/aymqwu981".

Weird. I don't get how this became the problem but removing/commenting it out fixed it.